# Store hierarchy file structure in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to store metadata of image files in mongoDB. Here is the case:

Each file includes a bunch of images + a list of metadata (key-value
   pairs) 
 Each image  has a list of metadata as well.

Metadata of the file and images are not fixed or known

My question is first is mongodb a good option to store this structure? If it is appropriate selection, how I can store this structure in mongodb in a way that I can search based on the metadata of the file as well as metadata of images with high performance?

What do you think about following structure? how can I search from it? What about its performance?

```
{ fileName: f1
  date : '2002'
  image1 :{

    imageId :1
    name    :"img1"
    focus   : 7

  }

  image1 :{

    imageId :1
    name    :"img1"
    focus   : 7
...

  }

  image2 :{

    imageId :2
    name    :"img2"
    insId   : 23
...

  }

}
```

I want some  queries like:

```
select * from file where focus =7 / insId =23 / date = 2002
```

I tried

```
{ "metaData" : [ { "key" : "imageId", "value" : 1 },{ "key" : "name", "value" : "imag1"    }, {"key" : "focus", "value" : 7 } ]}
```

to store metadata of one image or a file. By this structure I can create index on key and value and search by elemMatch, however, I cannot extend it 
for hierarchy structure. I am not sure if it is a good solution for the problem which I explained above.

I appreciate if you could help me!

Comment: I was surprised which I could not get any answer from stack overflow. I wondered if storing this structure in mongodb is not very common or my expectation from mongodb is very high. So what is real meaning of storing document in database? What is it good for?

Comment: Short answer: you can perfectly achieve what you are saying in MongoDB. Long Answer: the schema you have designed really depends on you business logic ie, what queries?, how often?, how many images within a file? Do you need operations to be performed atomically?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 
the queries are based on metadata of file or metadata of images or a combination. There is no rule which I can define.
The frequency of query is not very high. For example one per 30 min 
The number of images per files are at most 100-200 not more!

As I said, I used following structure:

{ "metaData" : [ { "key" : "imageId", "value" : 1 },{ "key" : "name", "value" : "imag1"    }, {"key" : "focus", "value" : 7 } ]}

On which I am able to defien index on key and value. but I donot know how to make it hierachical.

What do you think about that?

Comment: The thing is: if images don't have any sense outside the scope of a file then embed them within file document. Sorry but I dont get what you are saying about your structure (metadata and so on...) it has nothing to do with the schema you have posted.

Comment: The images does not have any sense out of the file and this is the reason that I want to store in this way. However in this structure, I cannot benefit from indexes. So I tried the second structure to store metadata of images in key-value structure to benefit from index. But I cannot extend it to have metadata of files and images! This is the problem

Comment: I got second structure from http://edgystuff.tumblr.com/post/47178201123/mongodb-indexing-tip-3-too-many-fields-to-index-use

Answer (score 0):

Why not embed all images in an array:

```
db.files.findOne()
{ 
 _id: ObjectId(...);
 fileName: 'f1',
 date : '2002',
 images : [
   {
    imageId: 1,
    name: "img1",
    focus 7
   },
   {
    imageId: 2,
    name: "img2",
    focus 17
   }
 ]
}
```

If you want to use the metadata to use indexes as you have proposed use:

```
db.files.findOne()
{ 
 _id: ObjectId(...);
 fileName: 'f1',
 date : '2002',
 images : [
   { metadata:[
      {key: "imageId", value: 1},
      {key: "name", value: "img1"},
      {key: "focus", value: 7}
   ]},
   { metadata:[
      {key: "imageId", value: 2},
      {key: "name", value: "img2"},
      {key: "focus", value: 17}
   ]}
 ]
}
```

and then:

```
 db.files.ensureIndex({"images.metadata.key":1,"images.metadata.value":1})
```

Comment: Why are you using `db.files.findOne()` here?  I think you want `db.files.insert()` instead, right?  `findOne()` is for querying the collection.

Comment: I use findOne() here to query the collection and show the output, thus the document's schema.